# How to redirect back from folder by window.location with alert message in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I tried like below many methodes some are responding resource not found and some are reloading same page unlimited time.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('test 9'); window.location='" + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/LoginPage.aspx';", true);

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "alert('Your session timed out.');window.location='../LoginPage.aspx'; ", true);

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Your session timed out');window.location.href ='../LoginPage.aspx';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me in chrome

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('test 9'); window.location='../Login.aspx';", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement like below will work, I have tested it. In this each "../" is one step back folder. In my example "CustomerLogin.aspx" is in the 2 folder back from the current page

You can put break point in Global.asax file or actual url being constructed to get exact file location generated.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "redirect", "alert('PWD');location.href='../../CustomerLogin.aspx'", true);
```

Comment: its not redirecting, again repeating same load

Comment: It seems that either your LoginPage.aspx is not located in one step back folder. 
Let everything run again. You will get error "The resource cannot be found. "
Now check value in "Requested URL: ".
This should be exact path to the LoginPage.aspx from Base directory.

Comment: can i do like this session["out"]="true"; Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");                                                          //at login page load check session value                                                        if(session["out"]=="true"){//display popup}

Comment: If you use Response.Redirect in code behide, you will not see alert box.

Comment: thats why i use response.redirect at last page and then displaying popup at pageload.]